# Merge few queries "SELECT INTO.." into one

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have list of selects like:

```
  SELECT id
  INTO   val_abc
  FROM   table_x
  WHERE  symbol = 'abc';

  SELECT id
  INTO   val_xyz
  FROM   table_x
  WHERE  symbol = 'xyz';

  SELECT id...
```

Is there possibility to merge few SELECTS from **SAME TABLE(!)** into one?

Comment: As each select retrieves a different row, this won't be possible (and if it is, this won't make the code more readable either)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can combine these queries like here:

```
select max(case symbol when 'abc' then id end),
       max(case symbol when 'def' then id end),
       max(case symbol when 'xyz' then id end)
  into val_abc, val_def, val_xyz
  from table_x
  where symbol in ('abc', 'def', 'xyz');
```

or even use pivot (Oracle 11 or newer):

```
select v1, v2, v3
  into val_abc, val_def, val_xyz
  from (select id, symbol from table_x)
  pivot (max(id) for symbol in ('abc' v1, 'def' v2, 'xyz' v3));
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b637a664c8b02fc24063f0243ceeb7c3)</sup>**

Note: if your query meets more than one matching row application throws error `too many rows` or `no data found` when there is no value. My solution uses aggregation so errors won't appear - it takes max value or null if nothing found. It doesn't matter if table_x has only one matching id for each symbol, but please be aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, several ways, for example

```
select id
from tablex
where symbol in ('abc', 'xyz')
```

or

```
select id 
from tablex
where symbol = 'abc'
   or symbol = 'xyz'
```

or

```
select id 
from tablex
where symbol = 'abc'
union all
select id
from tablex
where symbol = 'xyz'
```

Comment: aww... sorry, i forgot to add clause INTO. Could look again?

Comment: That, obviously, won't work if `val_abc` is a scalar variable (for example, declared as `val_abc number;`) as you can't put *many rows* into such a variable. You could do it in a loop, or restrict number of rows to exactly one (by applying `where rownum = 1`), but I guess that this is not what you want. Or, you could declare a custom type variable (a collection) and use `bulk collect`. There might be other options, but - please, explain what problem you are trying to solve as our suggestion depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this using `join`s, if you really want to:

```
SELECT abc.id, xyz.id
INTO val_abc, val_xyz
FROM table_x abc JOIN
     table_x xyz
     ON abc.symbol = 'abc' AND
        xyz.symbol = 'xyz';
```